# How to stop string repetition on array

Tags: java, arrays, string, random, repeat

We I have this college assignment where I have to Read a file with a list of names and add up to 3 presents to each one. I can do it but the presents are repeating and some people in the list are getting the same present more than once. How can I stop it so each person receives different variety of present each time?

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String path = "Christmas.txt";
        String line = "";

        ArrayList<String> kids = new ArrayList<>();
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Deliveries.txt");
        SantasFactory sf = new SantasFactory();

        try (Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileReader("Christmas.txt"))) {
            while (s.hasNext()) {
                kids.add(s.nextLine());
            }

        }
        for (String boys : kids) {
            ArrayList<String> btoys = new ArrayList<>();

            int x = 0;
            while (x < 3) {
                if (!btoys.contains(sf.getRandomBoyToy().equals(sf.getRandomBoyToy()))) {
                    btoys.add(sf.getRandomBoyToy());
                    x++;

                }
                
            }

            if (boys.endsWith("M")) {

                fw.write(boys + " (" + btoys + ")\n\n");

            }

        }


        fw.close();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a Set data structure instead of a List.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> if (!btoys.contains(sf.getRandomBoyToy().equals(sf.getRandomBoyToy()))) {
>     btoys.add(sf.getRandomBoyToy());
>     x++;
> }
> ```

Generates 3 toys, comparing 2 of them with each other first, and checking if the resulting boolean is present in the list of strings (which it presumably isn't), then appending the 3rd one.
Instead you should generate a single one, and use it for both checking and adding:

```
String toy = sf.getRandomBoyToy();
if(!btoys.contains(toy)) {
    btoys.add(toy);
    x++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The set interface present in the java.util package and extends the Collection interface is an unordered collection of objects in which duplicate values cannot be stored. It is an interface which implements the mathematical set. This interface contains the methods inherited from the Collection interface and adds a feature which restricts the insertion of the duplicate elements. There are two interfaces which extend the set implementation namely

```
for (String boys : kids) {
    Set<String> btoys = new HashSet<String>();
    btoys.add(sf.getRandomBoyToy());
    
    if (boys.endsWith("M")) {
        fw.write(boys + " (" + btoys + ")\n\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million  Mustafa Poya. It did work for me ! =)